# Order attribute first in woocommerce edit product

Tags: woocommerce

I need to display alwayas as first attribute in WooCommerce edit product the attribute "size" inside the tab "attribute" (woocommerce_attribute wc-metabox postbox).

NOTES:
I see that the order value is managed by this hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="attribute_position[1]" class="attribute_position" value="1">
```

IMG [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swGYL.png)